# Running C-Shell Script with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qprocess

I want to run the commands contained in `setup.csh` concurrently using QProcess.

The `deneme` variable is a command in the `setup.csh` file:

```
alias deneme "ls -la"
```

My purpose is to run a command guide in that setup.csh.

```
QProcess *process1=new QProcess(this);
process1->setWorkingDirectory("/home/intern2/elif/SETUP");
process1->start("tcsh",QStringList() <<"-c"<<"\"\"source /home/intern2/elif/SETUP/setup.csh\"\"" << "deneme" );

process->waitForBytesWritten();
process1->waitForFinished();
ui.textedit->append(process.readAllStandartOutput());
```

"deneme" command not working

Terminal output:

[image]

Gui code and output

[image]
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What problems do you have? Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us? And what do you mean by running "the commands contained in it concurrently"?

Comment: Are you coding in C or C++?  Choose one; don't choose both.

Comment: Maybe your script is missing the "shebang" line? Does the script run when you invoke it from a non-csh shell, e.g. bash?

Comment: I want to write using "c ++"  @JonathanLeffler

Comment: I edited question and added code, 

Run commands in the "setup.csh" file.

The "deneme" variable is a command in the setup.csh file.

In the setup.csh "deneme" command: alias deneme "ls -la".

First "setup.csh" file as source. Then I want to run the "deneme" command. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: What is  "shebang" @KevinKrammer

Comment: @elifmutlu ah, that's a name sometimes used for the `#/bin/shellname' line at the beginning of a script, i.e. the info that tells the current shell or process which shell interpreter to run the script with. Usually the very first line